# Auto keying on rotation order (euler or quaternion) channel

Tags: animation

I tested several options of auto keying, expecting keys to be generated in the Rotation Order channel.
However, all keying sets only generate keys for transforms and not for rotation orders.
The Whole Character keying set is fantastic because it generates keys for properties as well as transforms, but it was disappointing as it doesn't work for rotation order.

If you're dealing with multiple actions in one blend file, you'll also need to create a key for the rotation order as well. In most cases, quaternions work fine, but sometimes you need an euler.
Is there any special reason for auto keying options to exclude rotation order? If not, is there an option I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own keying set, including the rot order property: as in my example, go to the scene properties, click on the plus button to add a new keying set, rename it, right click on the loc property and choose "Add all to Keying set". Do the same for rot euler, rot quaternion and rot order, then choose this new keying set in the timeline dropdown menu.

[image]

Comment: Cool! I didn't know there was a Scene Keying Sets feature. Do I have to manually add transforms (along with rotation order) and properties for all control bones if my end purpose is to use them in Rigify? Or can I write a script to automate it?